# which queue dos a paused process resident?

Tags: linux-kernel, scheduled-tasks, signals, jobs

On Linux, when enter Ctrl-Z in a terminal, the foreground process will be stopped, as for the process in kernel, its state is marked as TASK_STOPPED. A sleeping process (in TASK_INTERRUPTIBLE or TASK_UNINTERRUPTIBLE state) is moved to a wait queue in the kernel, where does a process in TASK_STOPPED state resident? I've googled and searched related books a lot, no satisfied answer found. Excuse me for my poor English and Linux skills.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't get moved anywhere.  It remains on a CPU runqueue, and is never selected by the scheduler because its state is `TASK_STOPPED`.

Comment: Thanks! Could you provide some code in the kernel doing this job?